# Copy contents of Word document attachment in draft email into the body of same draft email

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I have a program that generates a draft email with an attached letter for the user to send on to the client. Most clients don't want the letter as an attachment but want it in the body of the email.

Is it possible to create a button that runs some VBA that opens up the attachment of the draft email, copies the text and pastes it into the body of the email?

I searched for something similar but couldn't find anything.

Comment: why take the extra step to get it from the attachment? Just slap the text straight from a word or txt doc into the email body. Lots of nice tutorials out there on how to automatically enter something to an email as plain text or even html formatted stuff.

Comment: Hi thanks, well the program are users are working with creates a draft email in their mailbox with the attachment for them so that is the starting point. I just want to be able to add a button or menu item that allows them to copy the contents  of the attachment into the body of the draft email.

Comment: `Most clients don't want the letter as an attachment`. Yes I got your question but mine is  why you'd want that considering it requires a) more interaction and hence points of failure and b) most of your clients don't like it.  To make a button that executes the macro itself is super easy ( in Outlook 2010 / 2013 / 2016 / 2019/ Office 365). Just go to  File-> Options-> Quick Access Toolbar and in the drop down list “Choose commands from” select: Macros and then pick yours. For the code itself I would work not off the attachment but as I said the original file containing the text.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean but the attachment is a handy link to the document with the relevant text in. It is not just one static document but a letter that has been auto generated with details about the matter we are working on for the client. The attachment is saved somewhere but I don't think it is possible to derive where it is in code when the starting point is the draft email.

Answer (score 1):

> Most clients don't want the letter as an attachment but want it in the body of the email.

VBA is not designed for distribution on multiple machines. If you really need to provide remote machines with a convenient way of handling incoming emails you need to develop a COM add-in instead. That is what they invented for! For example, you can do the job by creating a VSTO based add-in in Visual Studio, see [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019) for more information.

To read the attachment content you must save it to the hard disk first (see `SaveAsFile`). Then you can read the content of the file and paste the required information to the message body.